# Multiplying a certain row of a dataframe by the values of another row of another dataframe of the same dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I am populating by iterating through it by rows and trying to multiply the previous row by the values contained in another row of another dataframe of the same dimensions and then insert the resulting row into the first dataframe.

I've used .loc to filter the row of each dataframe and then I tried to use .mul, but I'm getting TypeError. Also for some reason, the first dataframe.loc results in a transposed series while the second doesn't and I'm forced to add a .transpose() to it

```
dfPortW.loc[i,"NAV":] = dfPortW.loc[i-1,"NAV":].mul(dfReturns1.loc[dfReturns1["Dates"] == date, "NAV":].transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution... not an elegant one, but it works.

I suspect the issue was being caused by the fact that pandas / python was not reading the dfReturns1 single row as a Series while dfPortW was one. What solved it was:

```
    j = dfReturns1["Dates"][dfReturns1["Dates"] == date]
    j = j.index[0]
    dfPortW.loc[i,"NAV":] = dfPortW.loc[i-1,"NAV":].mul(dfReturns1.loc[j,"NAV":], axis = 0)
```

this made sure both were series and it was a series .mul which worked just fine... again, not elegant but it works.

Comment: From what I can tell, you'd better off using shift() and cumprod() instead of emulating Excel-like behavior with Pandas.